# Prevent the text from moving a little left

Tags: html, css

I have a list which I have used as a menu.  When I hover over them I create a border around them but then when I do this, they move a little to the left! How can I prevent them from doing this?

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/5DKLm/)

**CSS:**

```
header {
    background-color: #eee;
    height: 45px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 1px #bbb;
}
#welcome_area {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5%;
}
#menu {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 5%;
}
#menu nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 5px;
}
#menu nav ul li a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 2px;
}
#menu nav ul li a:hover {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
.userWidget {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: 1;
}
.userWidget:hover {
    z-index: 2;
}
.user {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background: #fff;
    transition: width 0.3s, height 0.3s;
}
.user:hover {
    width: 350px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #eee;
    transition: width 0.3s ease 0.5s, height 0.3s ease 0.5s;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add an invisible border with 1px width to non-hovered links:

```
#menu nav ul li a {
    ...
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5DKLm/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Using less code, you can achieve the same effect.

Use `outline` to achieve what you need:

```
#menu nav ul li a:hover {
    outline: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
```

Comment: this is a nice solution if you do not apply `border-radius`